# Gitlab pull command occasionally failing using deploy key

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a situation where I have multiple remote devices periodically pulling from a gitlab repo, and they seem to work fine the majority of the time but will occasionally get an error:

> git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to exit code(1)
> cmdline: git pull -v origin    stderror: 'fatal: Could not read from
> remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists'

Normally I would assume that the ssh deploy key was incorrect, however the same key will work fine in the next iteration with no changes. The only thing I can think of is that all the devices are using the same SSH key, is it possible that only one is able to use the deploy key at a time and that the error is when two are trying to access it at the same time? I cannot find much evidence that this is the case though.